# filter working in pyspark shell not spark-submit

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

> > > df_filter = df.filter(~(col('word').isin(stop_words_list)))
> > >
> > > df_filter.count()

27781

> > > df.count()

31240

While submitting the same code to Spark cluster using spark-submit, the filter function is not working properly, the rows with col('word') in the stop_words_list are not filtered. 
Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `spark-submit` you are submitting along with what the expected output should be?

Comment: spark-submit pyspark-file.py. I'm expecting the number of records to be 27781 after filtering. However, after submitting the code, the spark dataframe stays the same! No filtering happened at all!

Comment: Is your expectation that after you run the filtering in the `df_filter` line that `df` will have 27,781 records as well because the filtering has been applied?  Because in your code the filtering is working.  `df_filter` has fewer rows than `df`, so it's confusing as to why you believe the filtering is not working.  Spark is a lazy interpreter.  When you're filtering your dataframe you're assigning it to a new variable `df_filter`.  When you call `df.count()` later that filter will not be applied.

Comment: In my actual code, I'm constantly updating 'df' and monitoring the number of rows by the code below.  df=df.filter(~(col('word').isin(stop_words_list)))    df.count(). I'm expecting the number of rows to be updated after filtering. However, the filtering is working in pyspark shell, but not while I submitted the code to the spark cluster using spark-submit.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering is working now after the col('word') is trimmed.
    `df_filter = df.filter(~(trim(col("word")).isin(stop_words_list)))`
I still don't know why it works in pyspark shell, but not spark-submit. The only difference they have is: in pyspark shell, I used spark.read.csv() to read in the file, while in spark-submit, I used the following method.
    `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`
    `from pyspark.sql import SQLContext`
    `session = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()`
    `sqlContext = SQLContext(session)`
    `df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option('header','true').load()`
I'm not sure if two different read-in methods are causing the discrepancy. Someone who is familiar with this can clarify.

Answer (score -1):

Try using double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df_filter = df.filter(~(col("word").isin(stop_words_list))).count()
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried double quotes around the column name! Still doesn't work!

Comment: Did you tried from pyspark.sql.functions import col

Comment: I imported col function before. Otherwise, there will be an error!

Comment: Please provide the Error Messgaes you are getting.

Comment: There is no error message. I just want to find out why my filtering above worked in pyspark shell, not in spark-submit.